# Android - Exoplayer shows blank screen while rendering mpd video

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I am using following test stream to render mpd in android exoplayer
https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/art-of-motion_drm/mpds/11331.mpd

following is my exoplayer code:

```
val adaptiveTrackSelection = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()
val trackSelector: TrackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(mContext!!, adaptiveTrackSelection)
mConcatenatingMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()
val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder().setUri(url).setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MPD)
            .build()
val dashMediaSource = DashMediaSource.Factory(DefaultDataSourceFactory(mContext!!, mContext!!.packageName))
            .createMediaSource(mediaItem)
mConcatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(dashMediaSource)
exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build()
        .also { exoPlayer ->
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
            exoPlayer.addMediaSource(mConcatenatingMediaSource as MediaSource)
            playerView!!.player = exoPlayer
            exoPlayer.prepare()
            attachEventListener(exoPlayer)
        }
```

I am getting player state STATE_READY, I am getting position update for each second and finally player state STATE_ENDED as well, but on screen it is always a blank screen. I am testing on samsung device with os android 12.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have shared is to a DRM protected video stream and the behaviour you are seeing is consistent with the player not displaying encrypted content.

If you just want to test ExoPlayer in general then you can simple choose a different stream which is not DRM protected.

If you do want to test this particular stream then you will need to set up the DRM information in ExoPLayer.

The ExoPlayer documentation provides guidance on this including the example below (https://exoplayer.dev/drm.html):

```js
MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
    .setUri(videoUri)
    .setDrmConfiguration(
        new MediaItem.DrmConfiguration.Builder(C.WIDEVINE_UUID)
            .setLicenseUri(licenseUri)
            .setMultiSession(true)
            .setLicenseRequestHeaders(httpRequestHeaders)
            .build())
    .build();
```

This is for Widevine which is the default DRM on Android and which your stream supports. You can see this by looking in the manifest you linked to and you will see the Widevine UUID listed in a Content protection element.

> ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed"

As an FYI, the full list of DRM UUID's is here: https://dashif.org/identifiers/content_protection/